# labels under markers

Tags: leaflet, tooltip

I have velow code that works 100% only problem is you have to click on the marker to see what the marker name is. how do i show a label or a tooltip without loosing the html link functionality?

```
     <?php echo $n1; ?>
    <?php echo $o1; ?>
    <?php echo $p1; ?>
    <?php echo $q1; ?>
    <?php echo $r1; ?>
    <?php echo $s1; ?>

        ["Office",-25.6641595,28.2375668]
    ];
  var map = L.map('map').setView([-25.890852, 28.090852], 10);
    mapLink = 
        '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';
    L.tileLayer(
        'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; ' + mapLink + ' Contributors',
        maxZoom: 18,
        }).addTo(map);

    for (var i = 0; i < planes.length; i++) {
        marker = new L.marker([planes[i][1],planes[i][2],planes[i][3]])
            .bindPopup(`<a href="${planes[i][3]}" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">${planes[i][0]}</a>`)
            .addTo(map);
    }
    
     function onClick(e) {

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `permanent` option when creating a tooltip to keep the marker open.
You can also use the `direction:'bottom'` option to position the tooltip below the marker.
https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#tooltip-permanent

```
.bindTooltip(`${planes[i][0]}`,{permanent:true, direction:'bottom'}).openTooltip()
```